# Using fabric with namespaces, is there a way to specify per-file env.shell

Tags: python, fabric

I use a fabric with namespaces to separate commands for dev and production servers

the structure is

```
fabfile/
    __init__.py
    dev.py
    prod.py
```

**dev.py** and **prod.py** both define different `env.shell` and one of them overrides another.

Is there a way to use per-file `env` configuration for fabric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up overriding the **@task** decorator like this:

```
from functools import wraps
from fabric.api import task as real_task

def task(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with settings(shell='/path/to/my/shell'):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return real_task(wrapper)
```

I can't use alias and other kwargs in this form, but it suits me.